# R: debugging a function: 'x' and 'y' lengths differ error

Tags: r, function, debugging, linear-regression

I'm just learning to create functions in R so I'm trying to make a function which graphs residual lines for a linear regression. I've already tried it and the code works outside of the function, but once I put it all into a function I get the 'x' and 'y' lengths differ error.
Here is my function:

```
`reslines <- function(x,y) {
abline(lm(y~x))
for(k in 1: length(y)) lines(c(x[k],x[k]), c(y[k], predict(lm(y~x))))
}`
```

The tracebook shows that the error occurs here:

```
6 stop("'x' and 'y' lengths differ") 
5 xy.coords(x, y) 
4 plot.xy(xy.coords(x, y), type = type, ...) 
3 lines.default(c(x[k], x[k]), c(y[k], predict(lm(y ~ x)))) 
2 lines(c(x[k], x[k]), c(y[k], predict(lm(y ~ x)))) 
1 reslines(a, b)
```

I've checked the lengths of each data set I've tried using the length() function, and they all match, so something is happening inside the function which appears to change the length or 'x' or 'y' or both.

Can anyone tell me what the error is and how to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: Check for NA's in the data.

Comment: First of all, you can't use an abline if you have not made a plot, thus, you must first plot the regression in your function

Comment: `c(x[k],x[k])` is a vector of length 2, whereas `c(y[k], predict(lm(y~x)))` is a vector of length `length(y) + 1`.  Also, instead of using a loop to plot multiple lines, consider using `segments`: `segments(x0 = x, y0 = y, y1 = predict(lm(y~x)))`.

Answer (score 0):

I think I fixed it, it was not super easy, mainly the problem was in your predict where you used y, x instead of y[k], x[k]. But there was a little bit more:

```
reslines <- function(x,y) {
  plot(y~x)
  abline(lm(y~x))
  lm.xy <- lm(y~x)
  for(k in 1: length(y)) {
    lines(c(x[k],x[k]), c(y[k], predict(lm.xy, data.frame(x=x[k], y = y[k]))))
  }
}
```

Now a test

```
set.seed(123)
reslines(rnorm(10), rnorm(10))
```

[image]